# Wrong Matrix Multiplication with MATMUL (Fortran)

Tags: fortran, matrix-multiplication, gfortran

I have the following minimal example saved in `minimalexample.f90:`

```
        MODULE FUNCTION_CONTAINER
        IMPLICIT NONE
        SAVE

        INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DBL = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(P = 15,R = 200)

        INTEGER :: DIMSYS, DIMMAT

        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(4,1) :: INSTATE_BASISSTATES

        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(2,2) :: SIGMAX

        REAL(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(2,2) :: BASISSTATES

        REAL(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(2,2) :: ID

        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(2,2) :: PROJECTOR

        CONTAINS

        SUBROUTINE INDEXCONVERTER(N,K,L)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN)::N
        INTEGER, INTENT(OUT)::K,L
        INTEGER::X, REMAINDER
        X = N/DIMSYS
        REMAINDER = N - (X * DIMSYS)
        IF (REMAINDER == 0) THEN
        K = X
        L = DIMSYS
        ELSE
        K = X + 1
        L = REMAINDER
        END IF
        END SUBROUTINE INDEXCONVERTER


        SUBROUTINE DENSITYMATRIX(X,RHO)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMMAT,1), INTENT(IN) :: X
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(2,2),INTENT(OUT)::RHO
        INTEGER :: J, K, L
        DO J = 1, DIMMAT
        CALL INDEXCONVERTER(J,K,L)
        RHO(K,L) = X(J,1)
        END DO
        END SUBROUTINE DENSITYMATRIX

        SUBROUTINE WRONGRESULT(X,RHONEW)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMMAT,1), INTENT(IN) :: X
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS),INTENT(OUT)::RHONEW
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS) :: RHO
        REAL(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS) :: ID
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS) :: SIGMAZ
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS) :: SIGMAX
        CALL DENSITYMATRIX(X,RHO)
        RHONEW = matmul(SIGMAX,rho)
        END SUBROUTINE WRONGRESULT

        SUBROUTINE EXPECTATION(X,D,ANS)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMMAT,1), INTENT(IN) :: X
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS) :: RHONEW
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS), INTENT(IN) :: D
        REAL(KIND = DBL),INTENT(OUT)::ANS
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMSYS, DIMSYS) :: TEMP
        INTEGER :: J
        REAL(KIND = DBL)::SUMM
        SUMM = 0.0D0
        CALL WRONGRESULT(X,RHONEW)
        TEMP = MATMUL(D,RHONEW)
        DO J = 1, DIMSYS
        SUMM = SUMM + DREAL(TEMP(J,J))
        END DO
        ANS = SUMM
        END SUBROUTINE EXPECTATION

        SUBROUTINE RK(ANSWER)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL(KIND = DBL), INTENT(OUT) :: ANSWER
        COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMMAT,1)::X
        REAL(KIND = DBL) :: X_EXPECTATION
        REAL(KIND = DBL)::T
        T = 0.0D0
        X = INSTATE_BASISSTATES
        CALL EXPECTATION(X,SIGMAX,X_EXPECTATION)
        ANSWER = X_EXPECTATION
        END SUBROUTINE RK

        END MODULE FUNCTION_CONTAINER

        PROGRAM ONE
        USE FUNCTION_CONTAINER

        IMPLICIT NONE

        REAL(KIND = DBL) :: ANS

        SIGMAX(1,1) = (0.0D0,0.0D0)
        SIGMAX(1,2) = (1.0D0,0.0D0)
        SIGMAX(2,1) = (1.0D0,0.0D0)
        SIGMAX(2,2) = (0.0D0,0.0D0)

        ID(1,1) = 1.0D0
        ID(1,2) = 0.0D0
        ID(2,1) = 0.0D0
        ID(2,2) = 1.0D0

        DIMSYS = 2
        DIMMAT = 4

        BASISSTATES = ID

        INSTATE_BASISSTATES(1,1) = (0.5D0,0.0D0)
        INSTATE_BASISSTATES(2,1) = (0.5D0,0.0D0)
        INSTATE_BASISSTATES(3,1) = (0.5D0,0.0D0)
        INSTATE_BASISSTATES(4,1) = (0.5D0,0.0D0)

        CALL RK(ANS)

        WRITE (*,*) ANS



        END PROGRAM ONE
```

When I run it, the compiler `cygwin` prints the answer as 1. That's all right - as expected. Now in the subroutine wrong, I play around with different expressions for `RHONEW.` For example, with `RHONEW = 2*RHO`, I get 2 as the answer. Again, as expected.

Now, I write `RHONEW = matmul(id,rho)`. I should get 1 as the answer since I am (trivially) multiplying with the identity before calculating the expectation value of `RHO` as defined in the subroutine `EXPECTATION`. Instead, I get `1.2732139384274929E-313.` Complete non-sense.

What could be going on? In my actual code, I want to do a complicated matrix multiplication of the form:

```
 RHONEW = UCONJ*RHO*U,
```

where `UCONJ` and `U` are linear combinations of matrices.

I'm not getting the correct result even for a trivial multiplication though. Possible errors which I can rectify to move on to my problem?

Note that the code is in all CAPS since I got it from my supervisor who had written it in fixed form. The code compiles with both the `.f` and `.f90` extensions.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Fixed format supports that. Also, Fortran is case insensitive - independent of the form chosen.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Okay, so let's ignore the case. I know it is; but I got the code written in this form. Also, the indentation shouldn't matter right. I'm using `.f90.`

Comment: @Aftab123 Sure, to the compiler it doesn't matter. But to the person trying to debug your code it does. You should make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I am trying to write an every more minimal example but I get one error: In the subroutine wrongresult, `RHONEW` has no implicit type.

Comment: You probably removed the declaration of `RHONEW`...

Comment: Please don't change the question to match the answer.

Comment: @Oh, yes. I was editing it prior to reading the answer while working on the second minimal example. I guess I didn't end up finalizing the edit. If I did, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `SIGMAX` inside the subroutine `WRONGRESULT` again. Therefore, it is scoped in the subroutine (again) and shadows the one defined in the module.

```
    SUBROUTINE WRONGRESULT(X,RHONEW)
      ! ...
      COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS) :: SIGMAX
      CALL DENSITYMATRIX(X,RHO)
      RHONEW = matmul(SIGMAX,rho)
      ! ...
```

The `SIGMAX` in this subroutine is never initialized, so `matmul` returns garbage.

Answer (score 0):

There are sometimes compiler switches like '-check uninit'. Using these generally is worthwhile, as well as '-warn unused', and '-check bounds'. Then once the whole thing is working and clean, then you can remove those checks and put in '-O2'.
Some indenting would be aesthetically pleasing.
For bigger arrays you can initialise the whole thing...
I think that the complex initialisation is worthwhile stated as CMPLX, but maybe gfortran does not require that??
 Examples:

```
    !... Indent
    DO J = 1, DIMMAT
      CALL INDEXCONVERTER(J,K,L)
      RHO(K,L) = X(J,1)
    END DO
    !... CMPLX ... array init
    SIGMAX(:,:) = CMPLX(1.0D0,0.0D0)
    SIGMAX(1,1) = CMPLX(0.0D0,0.0D0)
    SIGMAX(2,2) = CMPLX(0.0D0,0.0D0)
    !... Whole array init
    ID(:,:) = 0.0D0
    !... diag init
    DO I = 1, 2
      ID(I,I) = 1.0D0
    ENDDO
    !... Whole array init
    INSTATE_BASISSTATES(:,1) = CMPLX(0.5D0,0.0D0)
```

none of this is bad, but it may be easier to consider using assumed array sizes... But then you need to allocate and deallocate TEMP and RHONEW, so probably not any benefit in this 2x2. But an example is provided in case you end up with larger arrays:

```
    SUBROUTINE EXPECTATION(X, D, ANS)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(:,1), INTENT(IN   ) :: X
    COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(IN   ) :: D
    REAL(KIND = DBL)                   , INTENT(  OUT) :: ANS
    !~~Local~~
    COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS)      :: RHONEW
    COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS)      :: TEMP
    INTEGER                                            :: J
    !REAL(KIND = DBL)                                   :: SUMM

    CALL WRONGRESULT(X,RHONEW)
    TEMP = MATMUL(D,RHONEW)
    !SUMM = 0.0D0
    DO J = LBOUND(TEMP,1), UBOUND(TEMP,1)  !DIMSYS
      !SUMM = SUMM + DREAL(TEMP(J,J))
      ANS = ANS + DREAL(TEMP(J,J))
    END DO
    !ANS = SUMM
    END SUBROUTINE EXPECTATION
```